# function definition in header file in c++

Tags: c++, inline, header-files

I have a simple cpp project that has one .cpp file(**a.cpp**) and two .h files (**h1.h and h2.h**).

In a.cpp,  I have :

```
#include "h2.h"
#include "h1.h"
```

In h1.h, I have :

```
double abc = fun1(a, b); //using fun1() here. a and b are string types.
```

In h2.h, I have :

```
double fun1(string a, string b)
{ //definition
}
```

Error: in  h1.h => `fun1() in not declared in this scope.`

Query is, m I doing this right? can one put function definition in a header file? should I use inline here?

**Edit:**

here is the h1.h

```
void checkForOneToOneSimilarity(vector <string> & folder1, vector <string> & folder2)
{
    int i=0, j=0, l1 = folder1.size(), l2 = folder2.size();
    //chunking(folder1[0]);
    while(i < l1 && j < l2)
    {
        if(folder1[i] == folder2[j])
        {
            double similarity = fun1(folder1[i], folder2[j]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(folder1[i] > folder2[j]) j++;
        else i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike C, In C++ a function with no parameters is exactly that: a function that has no parameters. You need to declare and define it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `double fun1()` in h2.h,
but you called the function `double fun1(std::string, std::string)`.
The compiler searches the definition `double fun1(std::string, std::string)` which is not declared.

You should change the function header in h2.h to `double fun1(string a,string b)`

Comment: then what is the the right way to do it if I want the definition still in h2.h?

Comment: After your edit, where is the fun1() function called in h1.h?
please edit the function names to make the question clear.

Comment: what do you mean by function header? i just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

you declared *fun1()* in *h2.h* and called the function *h1.h* so when the compiler search about *fun1()* it will not found it 
try to *include"h2.h"* in the "h1.h" file

Answer (score 0):

You can place function definitions in header files.
but here two things are wrong

1. You are calling `fun1` inside h1.h , but it defined in h2.h. so h1.h cannot see the definition in h2.h.
   for overcome this include h2.h to h1.h
2. Your function call and definition miss match.

   - function definition should be

   `double fun1(string a, string b)
   { //definition
   }`

   - matching function call should be

   `double abc = fun1("some string 1", "some string 2");`

**Append:**
correct three files should be

h1.h

```
double addTwoStringNumbers (string a, string b)
{
 double tot = atof(a.c_str()) + atof(b.c_str());
 return tot;
}
```

h2.h

```
#include "h1.h"    

void showValue()
{
 double total = addTwoStringNumbers("2", "3");
 std::cout << total << std::endl;
}
```

a.cpp

```
#include "h2.h"

int main()
{
 showValue();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: no no, the parameters are there and I have tried including h2.h in h1.h but again, same problem.

Comment: check the three files I showed in the `Append` part